# Making calls to different version of different assembly

Tags: c#, .net

I have 2 versions of same dlls. Say named, Test.dll. I want to call 2 dlls from my console application.

I tried to use Extern alias. But it is calling new dll. I am calling these 2 dlls from my DAL class.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

This is not the default way of how you do things in .net, therefore coding will not be easy in such a manner. As @Johnathon Reinhart says in his answer, you will have to use `Assembly.Load` (by passing the fully qualified assembly name to the function). 
Like this:

```
Assembly asmOld = Assembly.Load("MyAssembl, Version=1.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ab1234567defabc1");
Assembly asmNew = Assembly.Load("MyAssembl, Version=2.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ab1234567defabc1")
```

Moreover, you will have to keep reference to both assemblies and then use `Assembly.CreateInstance` to create instances of the types you need. After that, you will have to call members using reflection ([something like this](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/csharp/threads/98148)). Like this:

```
Ojbect objOld = asmOld.CreateInstance("MyApp.Namespace.Classname");
Ojbect objNew = asmNew.CreateInstance("MyApp.Namespace.Classname");
objOld.GetType().InvokeMember("TestMethod", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,null,obj,null);
objNew.GetType().InvokeMember("TestMethod", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,null,obj,null);
```

To improve your code writing, you could use the [`LateCall`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.compilerservices.latebinding.latecall.aspx) from `Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices` to work with your objects. There is a nice wrapper for that by Andy Adinborough - http://andy.edinborough.org/Use-Late-Binding-in-C-Now-without-NET-4-0

Comment: thanks for quick response. However my method takes DTO object(custom object), need to findout way of executing it

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that these DLLs are .NET assemblies, and not just standard C DLLs.

If so, I think you can specifically load the assembly with the static [`Assembly.LoadFrom(string assemblyFile)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1009fa28.aspx). Then I think you can get a module from that assembly with [`Assembly.GetModule()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getmodule.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

you can use Assembly.LoadFile or using alias

- [Loading Multiple Versions of same Assembly](http://www.infosysblogs.com/microsoft/2007/04/loading_multiple_versions_of_s.html)
- [Using different versions of the same dll in one application](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/abhinaba/archive/2005/11/30/498278.aspx)